# Add together numbers from Comboboxes tkinter python

Tags: python, string, tkinter, combobox, integer

i want to add multiple values that the user select from different comboboxes. I then want to add together the values and display the total value next to the boxes. The problem seems to be that the "values" from the comboboxes are strings, and can therefore not be added together.
If you wanna run the program, just comment out the variable "totalvalues before the last for loop. (i know it looks wierd, i just tried to make a new program to show my problem)

```
 import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
win=tk.Tk() #window
win.title("Moskalkylator")
antalcomboboxes=4
mighty=ttk.LabelFrame(win,text='Welcome')
mighty.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=8 ,pady=4)

Items=['Wood','Iron','Plastic','Glass']
def click():
    calculate = ttk.Label(win, text="Your total number of items is : " + totalvalues.get()) # See row 27
    calculate.grid(column=1, row=0)
buttons_frame=ttk.LabelFrame(mighty)
buttons_frame.grid(column=1,row=8, padx=3, pady=3,sticky=tk.W)

calculate=ttk.Button(buttons_frame,text='Count', command=click).grid(column=1,row=8)
#Creates combobox 1
list1=list(range(11))
number_chosen1= ttk.Combobox(mighty,values=list1, state="readonly") #The number you pick in the combobox
number_chosen1.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=tk.W)
#Creates combobox 2
list2=list(range(11))
number_chosen2= ttk.Combobox(mighty,values=list2, state="readonly")
number_chosen2.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=tk.W)

###############

totalvalues=number_chosen1+number_chosen2 #This does not work! COMMENT THIS

###############

#Loop to get the names of the items above combobox
Items_order=0
row_move_loop2=0
for element in Items:
    article = ttk.Label(mighty, text=Items[Items_order])
    article.grid(column=1, row=row_move_loop2)
    Items_order=Items_order+1
    row_move_loop2=row_move_loop2+2

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are the values string representation of numbers? As in is it "5" instead of 5? If so all you need is to convert the values to integers using the "int" keyword. For example int(value).

Comment: I tried with that, but couldnt get it to work, my error messange states :  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Combobox' and 'Combobox'. If i print out the "value" (the number i select in the combobox) in the console as print(number_chosen1), i get " .!labelframe.!combobox"

Comment: That's because you are adding combobox + combobox **not their values** .You need to get the values of the combo boxes then add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `get()` method to get the values from `combobox` and convert them to integers. Also, don't keep creating new label everytime you want to display the count instead create the label once and use `configure` method to change the text.

Here is your corrected code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

win=tk.Tk() #window
win.title("Moskalkylator")
antalcomboboxes=4
mighty=ttk.LabelFrame(win,text='Welcome')
mighty.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=8 ,pady=4)

Items=['Wood','Iron','Plastic','Glass']

def click():
    global totalvalues
    if number_chosen1.get() != '' and number_chosen2.get() != '':
        totalvalues= int(number_chosen1.get()) + int(number_chosen2.get())

    calculate.configure(text="Your total number of items is : " + str(totalvalues))


buttons_frame=ttk.LabelFrame(mighty)
buttons_frame.grid(column=1,row=8, padx=3, pady=3,sticky=tk.W)

calculate=ttk.Button(buttons_frame,text='Count', command=click).grid(column=1,row=8)
#Creates combobox 1
list1=list(range(11))
number_chosen1= ttk.Combobox(mighty,values=list1, state="readonly") #The number you pick in the combobox
number_chosen1.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=tk.W)
#Creates combobox 2
list2=list(range(11))
number_chosen2= ttk.Combobox(mighty,values=list2, state="readonly")
number_chosen2.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=tk.W)

###############
print(number_chosen1.get())

totalvalues = 'None'

calculate = ttk.Label(win) # See row 27
calculate.grid(column=1, row=0)

###############

#Loop to get the names of the items above combobox
Items_order=0
row_move_loop2=0
for element in Items:
    article = ttk.Label(mighty, text=Items[Items_order])
    article.grid(column=1, row=row_move_loop2)
    Items_order=Items_order+1
    row_move_loop2=row_move_loop2+2

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

when u retrieve values as a string u need to convert them.

```
totalvalues=int(number_chosen1)+int(number_chosen2)
```

or

```
totalvalues=float(number_chosen1)+float(number_chosen2)
```